# siunitx and frac in numrange

Tags: siunitx

With `siunitx` (up to date on MacTeX 2014), I would like to use something simple like

```
\numrange{1/100}{1/1000}
```

But I just get an error.

Is there a way to typeset this with `siunitx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK fractions with `/` are not supported, when `siunitx` parses the input numbers. However the parsing can be disabled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\numrange[parse-numbers=false]{1/100}{1/1000}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/SIunits/SIunits.pdf) of package `siunitx`:

> **`parse-numbers`** The `parse-numbers` option turns the entire parsing system on and off. The option is made available for two
>   reasons. First, if all of the numbers in a document are to be
>   reproduced ‘as given’, turning off the parser will represent a
>   significant saving in processing required. Second, it allows the use
>   of arbitrary TeX code in numbers. If the parser is turned off, the
>   input will be printed in math mode (requiring `\text` to protect any
>   text in the number).
>
> ```
> \num[parse-numbers = false]{\sqrt{2}} \\
> \SI[parse-numbers = false]{\sqrt{3}}{\metre}
> ```

Comment: Multi-part numbers are not allowed in ranges: you can have `\num{1/1000}` but conceptually this is two numbers :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Then you want to introduce something like `\multipartnumrange`? ;-) Fun aside: `1/100` is just a different way to write a rational number, other forms: `0.01` or `1 %`.